Recover MySQL database after upgrade to 8.4 keyring encryption
I have a RockyLinux 9 server that was running MySQL 8.0.36 and used the keyring plugin (keyring_file.so) for at-rest encryption.
We upgraded the database version to 8.4, which removed the keyring_file plugin. The upgrade caused the database to not start.
I do not have a VM snapshot to revert to. I do have SQL dumps that I can use if the database can be started.
I began learning how to migrate to the component_keyring_file. It looks like this process needs the original keyring_file.so. I am not sure it will succeed without it. Can anyone confirm this?
I tried to downgrade MySQL by uninstalling 8.4 and installing 8.0. The database errored; the log had something about the downgrades not being compatible. I don't have access to the logs as I write this. Then I tried uninstalling again, deleting most everything in the /var/lib/mysql directory, keeping the \dumps and \binlogs directories, and installing mysql 8. The database will not start.
I need a method to get the database running either 8.4 with the new component keyring running or reverting to 8.0.

We ended up trying to uninstall MySQL 8.4 again. I'd forgotten to remove mysql-client; maybe that was part of it.
systemctl stop mysqld
dnf remove mysql-server mysql-client
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

dnf install mysql-server
systemctl enable mysqld
systemctl start mysqld

The keyring_file was where it was supposed to be.
ls /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/keyring_file.so

The database started successfully.
